# How can I copy a Gmail message to the Clipboard?

Tags: gmail, copy-paste

I just want to be able to copy all or part of a Gmail message to the Clipboard.

Can I do that?

Comment: Isn't Ctrl+C what you are looking for?

Comment: The answer is yes, but I assume you're asking the question because you're having a problem doing this. What have you tried that is not working?

Comment: What are you trying to copy? A part of the message? The whole thing? The headers? The full original message, with headers?

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> - Select All

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> - Copy To Clipboard

If you just want to copy part of what's on screen:

1. Mouse click at the beginning of the paragraph.
2. Click <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and hold.
3. Move your mouse to the last paragraph to copy.
4. Mouse click again. Your text will be highlighted. You can let go of <kbd>Shift</kbd> now.
5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will copy the highlighted text to the clipboard buffer.